# PHP: Split foreach result

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I've a scraper script:

```
foreach($html->find('td.Live') as $e)
echo $e->plaintext . '<br>';
```

The result will look like this:

```
name 1 status  <br>
```

And I really need to turn the result into 2 arrays like:

```
name_array = (name 1, name 2, name 3, name 4)
status_array = (status, status, status, status)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: paste complete output here so that we can sort out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$name_array = $status_array = array();
foreach ($html->find('td.Live') as $e) {
    $parts = explode(" ", trim($e->plaintext));
    $status_array[] = array_pop($parts);
    $name_array[] = trim(implode(" ", $parts));
}
echo "<pre>Names:\n", print_r($name_array, 1), "\nStatuses:\n", print_r($status_array, 1), "</pre>";
```

Comment: My output looks like this:
vaskemaskine 3 Optaget 0 
vaskemaskine 4 Resttid: 1:55 230 
vaskemaskine 5 Optaget 0 
vaskemaskine 6 Optaget 0 
vaskemaskine 7 Fri

And i need only 2 arrays with
Name = (vaskemaskine x, vaskemaskine x)
Status = (restid, fri, optaget)
Not anything else

Answer (score 0):

```
$name_array = $status_array = array();
foreach($html->find('td.Live') as $e) {
    $segment= explode(' ',$e->plaintext);
    $status_array[] = $segment[2];
    $name_array[] = str_replace($segment[2],'',$e->plaintext);
}
echo 'Name: ';
print_r($name_array);
echo '<br> Status:';
print_r($status_array);
```

Comment: $status_array are blank?

Comment: I had rechecked, it works fine for me. If $status_array don't have value then $name_array also will not return any value from this code. please check the spelling and workflow.